# How to get a value from a java program from a VB6 program?

Tags: java, vb6

Due to the importance of some legacy applications in my workplace, I was thinking if I could solve a problem in a VB6 app by doing the processing on a Java app instead, and then delivering the value back to VB6. For that, I'd need to run the Java app from inside the VB6 app, and then get a String back from it.

How would you suggest that I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formal web services (I'm looking at you SOAP) have a tremendous amount of overhead and rigidity, and something like REST or plain old XML or JSON over HTTP don't save on that very much.

You might be far better off using TCP with a very thin protocol on top of it.  Named Pipes would be better but VB6 has no native support for this.  Anonymous pipes might be ideal but VB6 never got native support for async pipes of any variety.

So the quick and not-so-dirty solution might be TCP.  You can add trivial framing such as a message length prefix or message termination delimiter, then design a payload format ranging from delimited text to fixed fields to XML or JSON or even a binary format.

Leave web services to their proper use case: cross-organizational interoperation over the Internet.